# Long GET parameters in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

I have a typical Controller Action that needs to process a search result and pass search parameters back to the view for use in pagination links (so pagination holds search state).

If my URL is like this;

```
/default/search/index/query/foo+bar/when/today/sort/asc
```

I can access each parameter like this;

```
$this->_getParam('query') // returns 'foo bar'
```

If I wanted to retain this way of key/value parameters using /search as the route, what router would I need to use (Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex, Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Route etc.) and how would I configure it by the ini file?

Am I correct in thinking the form method should still be GET even though it will construct the search parameters as ?query=foo+bar&when=today&sort=asc   ?

Answer (score 0):

I should make it like this.

In the controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->view->params = array ('query' => 'foo bar', 'when' => 'today', 'sort' => 'abc');
}
```

In the view:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url (array ('action' => 'search', 'params' => $this->params)) ?>">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. How would you suggest this be set up as a route?

Comment: Yes in general I will be using custom routes. I'm not unsure of what method to set the html form. Should it be GET or POST?